# Extract list from Sharepoint without using Get-SPWeb

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I don't have access to the Sharepoint server and can't use remoting, and therefore don't have access to `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell` which contains the SharePoint commandlets.

I also can't use 3rd party libraries which means I only have access to built in Powershell commandlets, or any .NET class.

How can I access a Sharepoint list using only built in Powershell commandlets or .NET classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are using SharePoint 2010 and you don't have access to the server itself and must interact with it remotely you have essentially three options:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh313619(v=office.14).aspx

You can use:

1. Client Side Object Model - this gives you a structured SharePoint classes approach to enumerating, viewing and interacting with SharePoint site artifacts
2. SOAP Web Services - Exactly what it sounds like...a set of XML SOAP end points that let you interact with a SharePoint site
3. REST Web Services - A set of endpoints that follow REST principles

FWIW, the CSOM libraries use the REST endpoints under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

In given scenario you can make use of **[PnP Powershell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)** which runs on client side. You just need to install small setup to enable PnP command on machine from where you will run Powershell.

Then you can use command **Connect-PnPOnline**  to connect to desired sharepoint site.

```
PS:> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com
```

Once you provide valid credentials you will have access to PnP Context for that particular site.

Then using **Get-PnPList** command you can fetch list data

```
PS:> Get-PnPList -Identity Lists/Announcements
```

For more information on PnP-Powershell please refer Documentation : https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Documentation

Hope it will help you..:)

Cheers,

Swapnil Lad

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the question that I can't download any 3rd party software.